# GIT repository over LAN

Tags: git

I am trying to setup a **GIT repository over LAN** in **Ubuntu** OS.
I am able to setup a GIT repository, but not sure **HOW TO** *expose the repository to other users in LAN*.
As it requires a server, I installed **OpenSSH-Server**. But don’t know **HOW TO** configure it.
Please point me to correct resource to read from.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, you need to check your openssh setup on Ubuntu server: see [this HowTo](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/setup-openssh-server-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Then you can follow [this article](http://www.urbanpuddle.com/articles/2008/07/11/installing-git-on-a-server-ubuntu-or-debian), which mainly recommend:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
$ mkdir ~/src
$ cd ~/src
$ git clone git://eagain.net/gitosis.git
$ cd gitosis
$ sudo python setup.py install
$ sudo adduser \
  --system \
  --shell /bin/sh \
  --gecos 'git version control' \
  --group
  --disabled-password \
  --home /home/git \
  git
```

go into your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and add git to the list of Allowed Users that can login.
copy your `id_rsa.pub` file over to your server somewhere (in our example we're using `/tmp`) and then run this command:

```
 $ sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_rsa.pub
     Initialized empty Git repository in ./
 $ sudo chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
```

From your local machine, test it out with this:

```
 git clone git@YOUR_SERVER:gitosis-admin.git
```

Configure gitosis for a new project. Use your favorite editor to create a new block under the gitosis one. It should look like this:

```
[group myrailsapp]
members = myNameAsInTheRsa.pub
writable = myNewApp
```

A couple of things to watch out in the above block.
First, make sure your name matches what's in your public key (that is, open your id_rsa.pub file and see that what the name says.
Second, make sure you spell writable correctly!

Once you're done, commit and push the changes up to the server.

```
$ git commit -a -m "created a new repository!"
$ git push
```

Comment: Note: if you are having problems with the `eagain.net`, you can use Github.

Answer (score 3):

Your best way of doing that would be to run a ssh server and limit your users to use **`git-shell`** for their login shell. You can install an ssh server properly by either running one of the following commands if it has not already been installed.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install dropbear
```

Then add `/usr/bin/git-shell` to `/etc/shells` by doing

```
sudo echo $(which git-shell) >> /etc/shells
```

Then use the `git-shell` instead of `bash` as your user shell. This will restrict the user to only being able to perform `git` operations when logging into the server instead of providing the user with a full she..